# Arduino inputString.indexOf with multiple variables

Tags: python, arduino, indexof

I am currently working on making an arduino monitoring device. The data is collected in Python and then the string is sent via serial to the arduino.

In Python the string looks like this:

```
    cpu1 = space_pad(int(my_info['cpu_load']), 2)
    cpu2 = space_pad(int(my_info['cpu_temp']), 2)
    cpu3 = space_pad(int(my_info['cpu_fan']), 5)

    # Send the strings via serial to the Arduino
    arduino_str = \
        'A' + cpu1 + '|B' + cpu2 + '|C' + cpu3 + '|'
    if serial_debug:
        print(arduino_str)
    else:
        ser.write(arduino_str.encode())
```

Ideally I want to make this string as large as possible, to include 10 variables, which I want to send to the arduino.

The arduino code looks at the string and it is supposed to read parts of the string and place them neatly on a display, each in it's own reserved space.

The problem is that I get garbled results. When the string is only made out of just one variable, then it shows just fine, where it should, as it should.

When adding an additional variable to the string, the code breaks and it mixes the results or displays them chaotically. My variables are all clean, just numbers, nothing fancy.

Below is the code I use on the arduino

```
#include <Wire.h>
#include <LiquidCrystal_I2C.h> // Library for LCD

LiquidCrystal_I2C lcd(0x27,20,4); // I2C address 0x27, 20 column and 4 rows

String inputString = "";            // String for buffering the message
boolean stringComplete = false;     // Indicates if the string is complete
unsigned long previousUpdate = 0;   // Long to keep the time since last received message

void printInitialLCDStuff() {
  lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
  lcd.print("CPU ");
  lcd.setCursor(7, 0);
  lcd.print("%");
  lcd.setCursor(11, 0);
  lcd.print("C");
  lcd.setCursor(17, 0);
  lcd.print("RPM");
  lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
  lcd.print("GPU ");
  lcd.setCursor(7, 1);
  lcd.print("%");
  lcd.setCursor(11, 1);
  lcd.print("C");
  lcd.setCursor(17, 1);
  lcd.print("RPM");
  lcd.setCursor(0, 2);
  lcd.print("MEM");
  lcd.setCursor(8, 2);
  lcd.print("MB"); 
  lcd.setCursor(17, 2);
  lcd.print("PWM");
  lcd.setCursor(0, 3);
  lcd.print("RAM ");
  lcd.setCursor(8, 3);
  lcd.print("GBU");
  lcd.setCursor(17, 3);
  lcd.print("GBF");
}

void serialEvent() {
  while (Serial.available()) {
    char inChar = (char)Serial.read();
    inputString += inChar;
    if (inChar == '|') {
      stringComplete = true;
    }
  }
}

void setup() {
  // Setup LCD
  lcd.init(); //initialize the lcd
  lcd.backlight(); //open the backlight
  lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
  printInitialLCDStuff();

  // Setup serial
  Serial.begin(9600);
  inputString.reserve(200);
}

void loop() {
  serialEvent();
  if (stringComplete) {

    // CPU1
    int cpu1StringStart = inputString.indexOf("A");
    int cpu1StringLimit = inputString.indexOf("|");
    String cpu1String = inputString.substring(cpu1StringStart + 1, cpu1StringLimit);
    lcd.setCursor(4, 0);
    lcd.print(cpu1String);

    // CPU2
    int cpu2StringStart = inputString.indexOf("B", cpu1StringLimit);
    int cpu2StringLimit = inputString.indexOf("|", cpu2StringStart);
    String cpu2String = inputString.substring(cpu2StringStart + 1, cpu2StringLimit);
    lcd.setCursor(9, 0);
    lcd.print(cpu2String);

    // CPU3
    int cpu3StringStart = inputString.indexOf("C", cpu2StringLimit);
    int cpu3StringLimit = inputString.indexOf("|", cpu3StringStart);
    String cpu3String = inputString.substring(cpu3StringStart + 1, cpu3StringLimit);
    lcd.setCursor(13, 0);
    lcd.print(cpu3String);    

    inputString = "";
    stringComplete = false;
    previousUpdate = millis();

    }
  }
```

My code is very dirty and it mostly an adaptation of another code, because while I can read code, I am terrible at writing it. Apologies if I made horrible mistakes that would make anybody cringe. I admit I am just dabbling with coding. This is why I made notes in the code often.

I expect my display to show like this:

```
CPU  60% 45C  900RPM
```

Where

```
cpu1=60
cpu2=45
cpu3=900
```

The "CPU" "%", "C" and "RPM" are written by the arduino on printInitialLCDStuff() { and not Python.

Instead I get this

```
CPU B45% B45|B45|C
```

and then the RPM is listed on line 3 at (0,0) as `"900|"`

Ideally I want to expand the string sorting to collect about 10 variables.

It looks to me like the problem is in the arduino code, since the Python script kinda checks out and outputs the string correctly. But I could be wrong.

The question is: am I using the wrong code to extract these variables and place them in their reserved space on the display?

Should I use something else to get the job done? I have been looking at documentation for the past 3 days but I couldn't find someone with a similar case. I found some questions here, but again, not quite what I am looking for.

Any help is appreciated. I am so frustrated with this code after trying hours daily for the past days that I am willing to reward anyone that can assist me with this code with a steam digital gift card as way to show my appreciation.

Best regards,
M

Comment: First of all, the prefix `A`, `B` in your python code are redundant, it will be easier and better to just send the data as `cpu1|cpu2|cpu3`. This will make the parsing easier.

Comment: Secondly, Arduino is C++, try to learn C++ and not writing Arduino code the python way. Learn how to use [strtok](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/) to parse the data into an array, you can then loop through the array and print it on the display.

Comment: Hi @hcheung, thank you for taking your time to answer this question. I sort of understand by what you mean with the A, B being redundant, but I am not quite sure how to define the code in their absence in a way that would work? What would give the limitation of each of the smaller string "extracts"? As for learning C++, I try to learn whenever I have the time a little bit, which is difficult to come by.

Answer (score 0):

Your code can be changed to make it work, however, it would be like patching it up. I think it is better to take a different approach.

First, on your Python code, the prefix `A`, `B` are become redundant and not helpful on the receiving side to parse the data. If you format your data as a string with `|` as the separator, it make it easier to parse, and it is also much easier to create a string like that in Python.

```
    arduino_str = "{}|{}|{}|{}|{}|{}|{}|{}|{}|{}".format(
         data0, data1, data2, data3, data4,
         data5, data6, data7, data8, data9)
         
    if serial_debug:
        print(arduino_str)
    else:
        ser.write(arduino_str.encode())
```

On the Arduino side, `Serial.readStringUntil()` would make the reading entire string until a `\n` (end of the string) is encountered. Once the entire string is received, you can use the `strtok()` function in C++ to split the string by the delimiter (in this case it is `|`) into an array, so the splitted array would looks like this:

```
    splitted[0] = data0;
    splitted[1] = data1;
    ....
    splitted[9] = data9;
```

You can then print the data in the array to the LCD.

```
    #include <Wire.h>
    #include <LiquidCrystal_I2C.h> // Library for LCD
    
    #define NUMBER_OF_DATA 10
    
    LiquidCrystal_I2C lcd(0x27,20,4); // I2C address 0x27, 20 column and 4 rows
    
    String incomingString = "";
    
    void setup() 
    {
      // Setup LCD
      lcd.init(); 
      lcd.backlight(); 
      lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
      lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
      lcd.print("CPU    %    C     RPM");
      lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
      lcd.print("GPU    %    C     RPM");
      lcd.setCursor(0, 2);
      lcd.print("MEM     MB        PWM");
      lcd.setCursor(0, 3);
      lcd.print("RAM     GBU       GBF");
    
      // Setup serial
      Serial.begin(9600);
    }
    
    void loop() 
    {
      // read data from Serial until '\n' is received
      while (Serial.available()) {
        incomingString = Serial.readBytesUntil('\n');
      }
      
      if (incomingString) {
        // convert the String object to a c_string
        char *c_string = incomingString.c_str();
        // make a copy of received data so that incoming data would not override the received data
        char temp[strlen(c_string)+1];
        strcpy(temp, c_string);
        incomingString = "";
    
        // parse the received string separated by '|' into an array
        char splitted[NUMBER_OF_DATA][10] = {'\0'};  // initialise an array of 10-ch string
        int i = 0;
        char *p = strtok(temp, '|');    // parse first element in the string
        while(p != NULL) {    // loop through the string to fill the array
          splitted[i++] = p;
          p = strtok(NULL, '|');
        }
    
        // update LCD with the data in the array
        lcd.setCursor(4, 0);
        lcd.print(splitted[0]);
        lcd.setCursor(9, 0);
        lcd.print(splitted[1]);
        lcd.setCursor(13, 0);
        lcd.print(splitted[2]);
        
        // print the rest of data
        
        lcd.setCursor(13, 3);
        lcd.print(splitted[9]); 
      }
    }
```

I wrote this based on your code and have not debug on an Arduino yet, so it might need some debugging if it is not work out-of-the-box. I hope this help you in learn some trick and a little bit of C++ string and char array.

Comment: Hi, I have tried to compile this in the arduino code and at if (n) { I get 'n' was not declared in this scope. To me, it looks like it should work, but I'm not sure, since I am in entirely new territory here.

Comment: sorry, `n` should be `incomingString`, I made the change, see the updated code. As I said, you might need to do some debugging along the way...

Answer (score 0):

[image]I figured out. Instead of trying to separate the string and allocate it all in a preselected space I just made one single string and just edited the string format itself. Now I have a 80 char string and is auto arranged by (0, 20), (20, 40), (40, 60) and (60, 80).

Because this is just a simple resource monitor I didn't really need anything fancy, just to display the info on the screen.

Here is what I did

```
# Prepare CPU string line #1
        cpu1 = space_pad(int(my_info['cpu_load']), 3) + '% '
        cpu2 = space_pad(int(my_info['cpu_temp']), 2) + 'C '
        cpu3 = space_pad(int(my_info['cpu_fan']), 4) + 'RPM'

        CPU = 'CPU ' + cpu1 + cpu2 + cpu3
    
        # Prepare GPU string line #2
        gpu1 = space_pad(int(my_info['gpu_load']), 3) + '% '
        gpu2 = space_pad(int(my_info['gpu_temp']), 2) + 'C '
        gpu3 = space_pad(int(my_info['gpu_fan']), 4) + 'RPM'

        GPU1 = 'GPU ' + gpu1 + gpu2 + gpu3

        # Prepare GPU string line #3
        gpu4 = space_pad(int(my_info['gpu_mem']), 4) + 'MB  '
        gpu5 = space_pad(int(my_info['gpu_pwm']), 3) + '% PWM'

        GPU2 = 'MEM ' + gpu4 + gpu5

        # Prepare RAM strng line #4
        ram1 = space_pad(float(my_info['ram_used']), 4) + 'GBU  '
        ram2 = space_pad(float(my_info['ram_free']), 4) + 'GB'

        RAM = 'RAM ' + ram1 + ram2

        # Send the strings via serial to the Arduino
        arduino_str = \
            CPU + GPU1 + GPU2 + RAM + 'F'

        if serial_debug:
            print(arduino_str)
        else:
            ser.write(arduino_str.encode())
```

Because the '|' separator was constantly showing up as the last character of the string, I just switched to a letter that I wanted to appear instead, basically duck-taping it. I used the character 'F' which also acts as the letter and is shown in the string.

As for the Arduino code:

```
#include <Wire.h>
#include <LiquidCrystal_I2C.h> // Library for LCD

LiquidCrystal_I2C lcd(0x27,20,4); // I2C address 0x27, 20 column and 4 rows

String inputString = "";            // String for buffering the message
boolean stringComplete = false;     // Indicates if the string is complete
unsigned long previousUpdate = 0;   // Long to keep the time since last received message

void printInitialLCDStuff() {
}

void serialEvent() {
  while (Serial.available()) {
    char inChar = (char)Serial.read();
    inputString += inChar;
    if (inChar == 'F') {
      stringComplete = true;
    }
  }
}

void setup() {
  // Setup LCD
  lcd.init(); //initialize the lcd
  lcd.backlight(); //open the backlight
  printInitialLCDStuff();
  lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
  lcd.print("Arduino PC Monitor");
  lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
  lcd.print("Waiting for data...");
  lcd.setCursor(12, 3);
  lcd.print("Ver 1.0");

  // Setup serial
  Serial.begin(9600);
  inputString.reserve(200);
}

void loop() {
  serialEvent();
  if (stringComplete) {

    // 1st line
    String cpuString = inputString.substring(0, 20);
    lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
    lcd.print(cpuString);
    // 2nd line
    String gpu1String = inputString.substring(20, 40);
    lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
    lcd.print(gpu1String);
    // 3rd line
    String gpu2String = inputString.substring(40, 60);
    lcd.setCursor(0, 2);
    lcd.print(gpu2String);
    // 4th line
    String ramString = inputString.substring(60, 80);
    lcd.setCursor(0, 3);
    lcd.print(ramString);

    inputString = "";
    stringComplete = false;
    previousUpdate = millis();

    }
  }
```

Yes, it is that lazy, it is almost as sophisticated as counting on your fingers. I love how simple it is. Anything can be edited on the fly and all it takes is minimal knowledge.

I can understand if I get banned for being this lazy.

Thank you for your help. I have noted the advice on string splits if I need to do something more complicated.

Best regards,
M